# SMS and Gmail notification volume

Tags: sms, audio, notifications, gmail, volume-control

Is there an app that can control the volume of notifications for separate apps like SMS and Gmail? I searched around and found a number of old threads that says it's not possible.  There was an app called WhoIsIt that did what I was looking for but it seems to have been discontinued.

Otherwise I guess I'll have to make a custom ringtone that's louder than normal and use different ringtones for SMS and Gmail.

I'm on Android 2.3 btw.

Answer (score 2):

## Quick Answer

Volume control is managed system wide. The Android OS doesn't support independent control per application, only per stream type.

## Technical

The [AudioManager Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) only provides developers a way to adjust the audio volume per Stream type, not per application running.

This means that when setting the volume for a specific stream, will affect the entire system.

Currently available streams:

- [STREAM_ALARM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_ALARM) - The audio stream for alarms.
- [STREAM_DTMF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_DTMF) - The audio stream for DTMF Tones.
- [STREAM_MUSIC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_MUSIC) - The audio stream for music playback.
- [STREAM_NOTIFICATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_NOTIFICATION) - The audio stream for notifications.
- [STREAM_RING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_RING) - The audio stream for the phone ring.
- [STREAM_SYSTEM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_SYSTEM) - The audio stream for system sounds.
- [STREAM_VOICE_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_VOICE_CALL) - The audio stream for phone calls.

Most of this screams exists since the [API level](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) 1, and continue to act the same way on the current API level 16.

Answer (score 0):

My Sprint Store Assistant Manager loaded MP3 Ringtone Maker from Google Play.  He used that for the SMS text notification sound.  I'm delighted since I now can hear when a text massage comes in.  The result can be volume adjusted.

Sadly Google Reader and Google Gmail are almost whisper quiet despite his efforts.

Comment: There are several apps on Google Play called "MP3 Ringtone Maker". Which one are you referring too?